# Query for Including Tweet Starred

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Assume a Twitter clone is being built with the following database schema:

```
User
- id

Tweet
- id
- user_id

Star
- id
- tweet_id
- user_id
```

In this case, the user has many tweets and each tweet has many stars where each star belongs to a user.

Using Rails's Active Record, could a query be built to retrieve all Tweet objects and include whether or not a star has been created by the current user?

Looking for a response similar to this:

```
Tweet
- id
- user_id
- starred (true)
Tweet
- id
- user_id
- starred (false)
Tweet
- id
- user_id
- starred (true)
```

Answer (score 0):

tweet.rb

```
def starred?
   star.present?
end

def self.tweets_with_stars
  hash = Hash.new()
  all.each do |t|
    hash[t.id] = [tweet: t.id, user_id: t.user_id, starred: t.starred?]
  end
  return hash
end
```

in your view.

```
 <% Tweet.tweets_with_stars.each do |key, value| %>
   Tweet ID: <%= key %><br>
   User ID: <%= value[0][:user_id] %><br>
   Starred: <%= value[0][:starred] %> <br>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Miler, thanks for answering. Unfortunately this will create a new query every time I check for `star.present?` I'm trying to solve this problem using a single query.